# Printing garbage value instead of maximum value from an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a newbie in programming.

I've tried this code to find out the maximum value in an array. I've also drawn the logic of this code on paper & it's coming out valid.

I'm wondering why this code is printing garbage value instead of max value.
Here is the code:

```
void main(){

    int size, i, max=0;

    printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int a[size];
    printf("Enter the elements:\n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<size; i++){

            if(a[i]<a[i+1]){
                max=a[i+1];
            }
    }
    printf("\nMax value is %d", max);
}
```

Comment: Also, `main` has return type `int`.

Comment: @user3121023 You should post an answer, no one addresses that as of now

Comment: @kmsharif: [Chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are not appreciated around here. Not rolling back anyway.

Comment: @user3121023: I realized why I'm getting garbage value.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've realized that I've done some minor mistakes rather than the main thing i wanted to know. That's why I fixed the minor mistakes.

Comment: @kmsharif: At least some of them, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code..

```
int main(){

int size, i, max=0;

printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
scanf("%d", &size);
int a[size];
printf("Enter the elements:\n");
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
  // Search Max Value
  max = a[0];
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (a[i] > max)
    {
       max  = a[i];
    }
  }
printf("\nMax value is %d", max);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While the code may be correct, it does not answer the question.

Comment: What happens for `size == 0`?

Comment: ??? I meant your initialisation of `maximum`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize max somewhere prior to searching the array (which the current copy of the post does do ... but the first one did not).  However, if negative values are entered, it probably makes sense to use `INT_MIN`.

```
max = INT_MIN;
```

And then you need to compare the current max value against the array elements (rather than the array elements against themselves.

Comment: I'd actually prefer to set `max` to the very first item.

Comment: @Mark - not clear. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Using 0 as the initial max value would produce an incorrect result if only negative values were entered (e.g., if you entered -1 and -2 they would be less than 0 and, thus, 0 would be reported as the max.

Comment: @kmsharif: If you initialize max to some value (either INT_MIN or Jongware's good comment of using the first array value), then compare the current max against each array element (rather than a[i+1]).

Comment: @Jongware: Only works if you can guarantee there **is** a first element.

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, I worked that way & it worked out :)

Comment: @Deduplicator: there is always a first element, I think. If there is an exception. How?

Comment: @kmsharif: `size == 0`?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Oh, I see.
If user input array size as 0 the program doesn't allow me to take the input of array values. But it prints a garbage value as maximum. So How to get rid of this?
I meant, if user input size as 0. The program should exit rather than printing maximum value.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I found a way to get rid of this :)

Answer (score 2):

At this point, in your code, you're going outside of your array. You're also not comparing the element of the array to the current `max`, but to the next element in the array. This would be for sorting an array, but not finding the maximum value.

```
for(i=1; i<=size; i++){ /* i<=size */ you go one beyond
    if(a[i]<a[i+1]){ /* when i==size, you're 2 outside of your array */
        max=a[i+1];
    }
}
```

You can have `i<(size-2)`, but it's not very pretty.

You can also set `max` to the first element of the array, and loop from the second element.

```
max = a[0];
for(i=1 ; i<size ; i++){ /* loop to the end of the array */
    if(a[i] > max){ /* compare current space to max */
        max = a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: @awesomeyi It wasn't when this answer was posted

Comment: @AntonH: I realized why I'm getting garbage value. And it worked through your described method :)

Comment: @AntonH Umm, yes it was: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23573593/1

Comment: @awesomeyi I never said it wasn't.

Comment: @AntonH confused names srry

Comment: @awesomeyi No prob. I honestly hadn't noticed that `max` had been initialised on my first read of OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

1. `main` has return type `int`, always. Valid prototypes:

   1. `int main()`
   2. `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`
2. Starting with 0 as initial value for `max`instead of `INT_MIN` means you have an implicit element of value 0.
3. Always test the return value of `scanf`, it might not succeed.
4. Your second loop tries reading `a[size]` and `a[size+1]`, while your array only goes to index `size-1`.

   1. Correct the termination condition to `<`.
   2. Correct the comparison to compare `a[i]` with `max`.

Comment: I realized why I'm getting garbage value by a[size] & a[size+1]. Not clear about ""Always test the return value of scanf, it might not succeed"". Can you please clear that?